# Finding number of scores for each player

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying add um the number of score items each player has allocated to him and finding it problematic to return the number of scores each player has attributed to him. My code is as follows, but I just cant seem to get over the final hurdle:

```
with open("players.dat") as f:
    group = []
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        group.append( (fields[0], int(fields[1])))
        print(group)

from collections import deque

player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split()
        player_stats.setdefault(name, deque(maxlen=3))  
        player_stats[name].append(int(score))

print(player_stats)
print(len(score))

player_totals = {name: sum(scores) for name, scores in player_stats.items()} 
print(player_totals)

player_totals = {name: max(scores) for name, scores in player_stats.items()} 
print(player_totals)

player_totals = {name: min(scores) for name, scores in player_stats.items()} 
print(player_totals)

#testing counting number of scores for each player
#from collections import Counter
#items = Counter(val[1] for val in player_stats.values())
#print(items)

player_totals = {name:len(score)}
print(player_totals)
```

My data file is:

```
rooney 12
rooney 23
rooney 56
rooney 27
ronaldo 14
ronaldo 34
messi 23
messi 45
messi 12
messi 56
```

I am basically trying to find the average score for each player.

Comment: Why are you using a `deque` object here? That'll only ever store the *last 3 values* rather than all values.

Comment: I only need the last three values. And then for each player I just need to know how many values are stored. I have the total, max and min for each player but I also need the average which is why I need to know how many values each player has stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`collections.deque()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> In addition to the above, deques support iteration, pickling, **`len(d)`**, `reversed(d)`, `copy.copy(d)`, `copy.deepcopy(d)`, membership testing with the `in` operator, and subscript references such as `d[-1]`.

*Emphasis mine*.

To get the length, just use `len(scores)`:

```
player_averages = {name: sum(scores) / len(scores) for name, scores in player_stats.items()}
```

Comment: is there a way of adding a sort on alphabetical for name and then display the average for each player?

Comment: @DarthSidius: just use `for name in sorted(player_averages): print(name, player_averages[name])`; the `sorted()` call on a dictionary gives you a list of sorted keys.

Comment: is there a -key for reverse order for the sorted() function?

Comment: @DarthSidius: `sorted(player_averages, reversed=True)`.

Comment: ah yes of course...cheers----however, it is saying invalid keyword for this function...